# Oracle SQL - ORA-40478 - Returning large json in CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I wanted to know what I'm doing wrong in my execution, I created a package to build a dynamic query, but as I'm testing for a specific table, I passed the query that the package generated directly to a `CLOB` variable.

Context: this query returns the table values ​​in JSON structure, when I execute: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query`. This normally works for other tables, but for the table I'm testing on, it would return a JSON longer than 33k characters, which returned this error: `ORA-40478: output value too large (maximum: 4000)`, but I'm using the variable like `CLOB`, should assume much more than 4000.

Is there a problem with the way I execute the query and pass it to an output variable, when it is a CLOB? Because the generated query in `v_query`  does not exceed the limit of a `VARCHAR2`, and the only thing that changes is the "ROWID" passed in the WHERE clause, at the end, so I imagine the problem is in the return (which would be the generated JSON).

PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    v_query CLOB;
    o_return CLOB;
BEGIN
    v_query := 'SELECT JSON_SERIALIZE(JSON_OBJECT(...
    WHERE rowid = ''AAAgDXAAMAAAIL9AAN''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query INTO o_return;

    htp.p(o_return);
END;
```

The query in `v_query`  is already configured to return `CLOB`. Something like that:

```
SELECT JSON_SERIALIZE( JSON_OBJECT(
    'surname' : column_X,
    'surname' : ( SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG ( JSON_OBJECT(
    'surname' : column_Y
    ) ABSENT ON NULL RETURNING CLOB) as data 
    FROM table_Y
    WHERE column_Y = column_X), [...] 
    .
    .-- rest of the query
    .
    [...]) RETURNING CLOB ) RETURNING CLOB PRETTY ) as data
FROM table_X
WHERE rowid = 'AAAgDXAAMAAAIL9AAN';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions working with JSON objects in Oracle. The issue is probably caused by JSON function in your code.  Try it using *AGG json functions returning clob...

From the docs:
**Result Returned by SQL/JSON Generation Functions**

The generated JSON data is returned from the function as a SQL VARCHAR2 value, whose size can be controlled by the optional RETURNING clause. For the **aggregate SQL functions** (json_objectagg and json_arrayagg), **you can also specify CLOB** as the SQL data type **in the RETURNING clause.**
More here --> [enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-C0F8F837-EE36-4EDD-9261-6E8A9245906C)

Comment: Got it, I actually realized that it was just missing declaring `RETURNING CLOB` in the closing of the `JSON_OBJECT` which is inside the `array` too, with that it worked, it didn't return the size error anymore, but only when I execute the query directly.

Nnow when I run the query passing it to a variable, using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, it gives me another error: 

`ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`

Does the "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" have any size limitations too? Because this query will be built dynamically, so I will have to use "execute".

Comment: I discovered that in fact it only returns this new error, when the JSON returned from `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, is effectively greater than a VARCHAR2(32767), when it returns a JSON smaller than "32767", it works perfectly :(